# Why is my X Display unaccessable?

Tags: python, user-interface, x11

I wanted to start GUI developing on Raspbian, so I set up PyQt4. I ran a simple example code, and it threw an exceptation because it couldn't access the X server. I thought OK, PyQt4 sucks on Pi, so I removed it without remembering the error text, and installed wxPython instead. Another example code, the result: `Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set propely?` (later I echoed the $DISPLAY variable, and it turned out to be :0.0.) So I gave up the idea of GUI developing, started to work with Python Imaging Libary (PIL, actually Pillow). Called the .show() function (that shows the image in a window). `Error: unable to open X server.`

What the hell is the problem with that X? (I am a beginner so please be detailed.)

I ran all codes in Geany on the RaspberryPi itself. I have not used ssh yet.

---

Codes:

The PIL code:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.new(str(1), (8, 8)) 
image.show()
```

The PyQt code (from http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/firstprograms/):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt4 tutorial 

In this example, we create a simple
window in PyQt4.

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: October 2011
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The wxPython code (from http://zetcode.com/wxpython/firststeps/):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# simple.py

import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'simple.py')
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Sometimes I have similar issues when trying to run graphical applications from the command line as root... Are you trying to run your examples as a different user?

Comment: So, you have some shell running, and if you `echo $DISPLAY` it gives you ":0.0" but if you run `xterm` it gives you an error?

Comment: @Davide this could be the issue since Geany runs the code from command line, and I added sudo to both the complie and run commands. (Complie needs it, and gpio management needs too.) Will try it out tomorrow if an executable fails too.

Comment: For the record: the problem was sudoing the code. Running it normally gave me no error at the end.